# How to scan words, lines and their properties on the text?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, swift

I'need to scan a document. It's not OCR, let me show you:

--Example--

**Table of Contents**

*Some Italic Words*

Sentence 23

--End--

Suppose that as a ".doc" formatted text. I need to scan it line by line and understand the first line is bold, second is italic and third one includes space after first word and followed by a number. Reason i want to recognize them is i need to categorize them in a table view like bold lines italics, numbereds etc.

I'm okay in both swift and objective-c but totally clueless about document scanning. If you offer any reference, framework or approach i would be grateful to hear.

Comment: You say "Suppose that as a doc formatted text." What does that mean? Is this file data of some sort? You say it's not OCR, but what IS it? 

Do you mean Microsoft word ".doc" format? If that's the case, you need a library that knows how to read that file format. Or is it a .rtf file, or some other format? Without that information your question is pretty much meaningless.

Comment: Yes @DuncanC it's doc. I've edited question to make it more explicit, thank you.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc313153%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

1. variant: your doc is really a docx. (docx is xml) Parse the XML. The format defines XML tags it uses to mark stuff bold or italic or whatever -- a docx is kind of like html.
2. variant: If your doc is really a doc! then we are not talking about xml but a binary format. It is also document and you can go parse it but I don't think will be easy

---

## BUT

There is a library I know: doc2text that can parse a lot of stuff. (http://www.textlib.com/doc2text.html)
We used in past projects and it did an okay job and using this saves you A LOT of effort writing your own parsers